# Toshiba Satellite L650D display broken

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, gpu, laptop-display

The laptop screen doesn't work. External via VGA works like on the photo below:

[image: Display not working photo]

I read somewhere that by pressing shift+f8+power button after taking out and putting back in the battery might fix the issue and it did revert the situation for a few seconds( The internal screen looked like the external on the photo with the artefacts and everything).

Last night windows 10 installed some updates. After one rollback it came back alive but after a few minutes blue screen and back to this situation again(The fact that it fixed the issue for a few minutes might have been a coincidence I guess)
The computer boots into windows recovery. Rollback doesn't work anymore. Choosing to boot normally fail with the light blue screen with sad emote that something went wrong and a QR code. I can't even read it because the screen looks a lot worse then.

BIOS looks exactly the same. I booted ubuntu from a pen drive. Looks exactly the same. I couldn't mount the windows partition as it said that it hasn't been closed properly and that I shouldn't do it unless in readonly mode. I could recover the data and reinstall but the screen issue won't be gone that way.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: nominally that looks like a dead screen, but if it does it on both internal & external displays, it's a dead graphics card.

Comment: That was my first impression too. Maybe I'll put it in an oven or something. It had been very hot but now it has been colder for a few days. :) As the graphic card is integrated here I think repair/replacement is worth more than the laptop itself.

Comment: I have seen those artifacts with bad or improperly seated memory modules. Re-seat the memory modules.

Comment: @Moab are you talking about GPU RAM or normal RAM?

Comment: If software (i.e. OS) provides even a temporary fix, you might try running a Linux version from USB (or CD), e.g. Ubuntu Live, https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0

Comment: I booted ubuntu, same problem. I'm comming to a conclusion that it's a problem with the motherboard and/or its integrated graphics card. Will have to price it and decide whether to sell it for parts or try to repair.